# Can I Install Ubuntu on EEEPC 900

Tags: eeepc

can i Install Ubuntu 12.10 on my EEPC900 ?
**The Second SDD is broken** , so there are only still a **4GB Harddisk** , 1GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You need laptop with Windows, then you should download and install LiLi USB Creator (it if free program to create bootable USB memory stick), you will need Ubuntu ISO from Canonical, USB memory stick 4GB and that is pretty much it. Install Lili USB Creator, download Ubuntu from Canonical, then insert your USB memory stick and open LiLi USB Creator. You have to find your USB in drop down menu, then you have to choose your ISO from Downloads, make sure to check that USB memory is formatted in FAT32 and press the little lightning in the end. Your USB memory stick will be ready in few minutes.