# how to boot iso. file via torrents

Tags: boot, bittorrent

I downloaded xubuntu 16.04-desktop iso.torrent in order to install on my eee pc 900a. how do I go about creating a bootable usb with the torrent file? And furthermore how to install it on the netbook which currently has the android x86 os on it. I installed it to see how it runs and didnt like it but now I'm having a hard time taking it off or rather replacing it with something else.

Comment: you have to download the iso first.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/265812/can-i-install-ubuntu-on-eeepc-900 seems to have the answer you need.

Comment: What OS are you going to create the bootable drive with? If it is a *nix flavor you can use dd instead of unetbootin

Answer (score 1):

The file you downloaded is a torrent file. You need to open the file with a torrent manager like [this](http://www.utorrent.com/intl/en/). After downloading the complete iso file, burn it to your pendrive with tools like [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/). You can easily find other information on google.

Answer (score 1):

### Getting an iso file via torrent

The following official Ubuntu link

[www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

explains it like this

> **BitTorrent**
>
> BitTorrent is a peer-to-peer download network that sometimes enables higher download speeds and more reliable downloads
>   of large files. You will need to install a BitTorrent client on your
>   computer in order to enable this download method.

There are several torrent clients available for Ubuntu and the Ubuntu family flavours (for example Xubuntu) as well as for Windows and MacOS.

I use the torrent client **Transmission** in Lubuntu and it works well for me. You can start it via Dash in standard Ubuntu or via the menu in most other operating systems or via the following command line (in Linux)

```
transmission-gtk xubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent
```

and it will fetch the iso file for you. The torrent process will check the `md5sum` automatically and it is often but not always faster than downloading the iso file directly. (Some internet service providers block torrents because they think that all torrent actions are illegal.)

### Creating a USB boot drive from an iso file

Use a tool to create a USB boot drive fron an iso file. **The cloning method** works with all Ubuntu and Ubuntu family iso files. It is a very reliable method.

- In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions you can use the **Startup Disk Creator**.
- In Linux you can use **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)**
- Please avoid **`dd`**, a very powerful but also dangerous tool, often nicknamed 'Data Destroyer' and 'Disk Destroyer' because it does what you tell it to do without questions. And telling it to overwrite the family pictures in a minor typing error away.
- In Windows you can use **[Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)**.

There are also **extracting tools**.

- In Windows there are several extracting tools. **[Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)** can be recommended.
- In Linux there are several tools too, for example **Unetbootin** and **LiLi**, that are also recommended by many people (but I think the cloning tools are more reliable).

You find more details at the following link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)