# Trying to boot ubuntu from usb

Tags: usb, windows-7, usb-installation

Hi guys I have used rufus to get the ubuntu iso onto my usb but when I go to boot from the usb in the bios it gives me an error saying something along the lines of: "bus: MMIO write of 80000276 FAULT at 10eb14" and then the last line says: "gr: init failed, -110" can someone please tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked with `md5sum` that the downloaded iso file is correct? See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: Alright I just checked the md5sum and it says the sums are different,do I just need to repeat the process with the right iso file?

Comment: You should download the file again until you get the correct md5sum. If you can use a torrent file, the fetching process will automatically check the md5sum, which is a great advantage if the internet connection causes problems. See this link about the torrent method, https://askubuntu.com/questions/802268/how-to-boot-iso-file-via-torrents/954163#954163

Comment: And yes, I think Rufus is a reliable tool to create a USB boot drive.